# How can I have content in a React app excluded from the build?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, create-react-app

I have a react app, made with create-react-app. In the app I have created a page for the style guide that shows all colours, fonts, buttons etc. so that when I am working locally I can see clearly in one location all the styles exactly as they appear in other places in the app. However I don't want this page included in the build, how do I exclude it?

I don't mind to run a seperate npm command and have the style guide running on a seperate port if that is a solution, but it must be referencing the exact same components as the app itself.

Comment: Try to add that file in `.gitignore`.

Comment: That would just remove it from the repository

Comment: you can simply do not render the page if you are in production mode

Comment: @Anton Yes, that is an option however I would like to avoid it in the build altogether so that it does not add to the file size.

Comment: @Michael then you may go the way of writing a small bash script, which will do some *sed* to remove it from the including into other components, optionally  remove the component file itself (but i may be not necessary). then you will do your build, and revert the git changes after.
you can add you commands into cmd execution inside of your packages.json, so later you just  do *npm/yarn run build* and have the logic done.
the solution may be rather ugly, but should work, and basically, ~20min to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://storybook.js.org does exactly what I require here.